# Xcode organizer icon doesn't meet size requirements when is actually do

Tags: ios, xcode, newsstand-kit, xcode-organizer

I trying to upload a newsstand application for ipad. I have a icon file that is 72x72 and 72 dpi. But when I am trying to submit it trough the Organizer I got a error that says that the icon doesn't meet the size requirements and the size is 0x0. I have checked the metadata in photoshop and in Finder, also Xcode, and effectivily says that the size is 72x72.

The plist source:

```
<key>CFBundlePrimaryIcon</key>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
        <array>
            <string>MoD72.png</string>
        </array>
        <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
        <false/>
    </dict>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstall or update the [Application Loader](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/apploader/ApplicationLoader_2.5.1.dmg) to the latest. This is a known bug and nothing to do with your icon images.